# Can something be done about this User?

Tags: discussion

This user is repeatedly rude and abusive.

They posted rude comments (the same ones yesterday that were removed, and now they are reposted.

See [most difficult subject in physics/mechanical enginering - want to know](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/40209/10902)

This user also posted on Electrical Engineering and that post was removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user in question was suspended after their original outburst. If they come back and still cause problems, they will be delt with appropriately.

As long as these things are flagged, they will be taken care of. Thank you to everyone who flags posts and votes!